# How to add button with options in each row in the table

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin
How to add button with options in each row table like the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlTdi.jpg)

Comment: That is not part of the phpMyAdmin interface, so your question is quite unclear to me.

Comment: How to add button with options in each row table with php